# Triggering post build and passing in branch name from successful build

Tags: teamcity

I've used Google and looked at the [Docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger) but can't find an answer.

I want to trigger another build or a rake script to do some cleaning up of files after a successful build.  I currently use Rake to do my build and pass in `%teamcity.build.branch%` to it.

I would like to know if I can pass the same branch name of the successful build to the triggered build or script. I can then use this to do some tidying up.

Thanks

Comment: How can I pass the branch name to a script that needs to be run from teamcity as a build step

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [finished build trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger), you need to add [snapshot dependency](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Snapshot+Dependencies), with "Run build on the same agent" option enabled. This way, cleanup will run after each build, on the same agent.

You then will be able to refer to original build's branch name using [dependencies parameters](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties):

```
%dep.<original_bt_id>.teamcity.build.branch%
```

Comment: Can I copy and paste that in my new build config or should <original_bt_id> be populated with something?

Comment: The snaphot dependency goes on the new post build confuiguration right?

Comment: @Jon you should populate it with build configuration ID of the original build.
See this for details: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-BuildConfID

Comment: post build configuration must have snapshot dependency on the original configuration.

Comment: I've almost got it but the new build isnt triggered. Its queued but says no agents http://i.imgur.com/O0VlGlV.png. If I look at the project I see this http://i.imgur.com/SS62X4B.png

Comment: @Jon - angle brakets should be omitted.

Comment: Actually its not triggering non "master" branch builds. Its got them in "Pending" it just doesnt execute them. The build trigger has this for branches +:refs/heads/*

Comment: Which configuration is not triggered? The original one? Or the cleanup one?

Comment: cleanup but i've moved it now as a new build step on the original. thanks for all the help

Comment: Cleanup does not need vcs build trigger. The only trigger that should be configured for cleanup is Finished Build Trigger, pointing to original configuration.